# restoring db getting "no files are ready to rollforward" error

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

When I try to restore a DB file I am getting following error:

```
 The log or differential backup cannot be restored because no files are ready to rollforward.
```

My Back up SQL

```
BACKUP LOG [ICT_IdealComputer]
TO DISK = 'C:\ICT\ICTBackup.bak'
WITH NAME = 'ICT-Transaction Log Backup',
SKIP,
NOUNLOAD,
STATS = 10

BACKUP DATABASE [ICT_IdealComputer]
TO DISK = 'C:\ICT\ICTBackup.bak'
WITH NAME = 'ICT-Full Database Backup',
SKIP,
NOUNLOAD,
STATS = 10
```

Restore statement:

```
USE [master]
GO

RESTORE DATABASE ICT_IdealComputer
FROM DISK = 'C:\ICT\ICTBackup.bak'
WITH REPLACE, NORECOVERY, 
MOVE 'ICT_IdealComputer' TO   'C:\ICT\ICT_Ideal\App_Data\ICT_IdealComputer.mdf',
MOVE 'ICT_IdealComputer_log' TO 'C:\ICT\ICT_Ideal\App_Data\ICT_IdealComputer_log.ldf';
```

I did tried with different option, googled around but no luck. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a single file as the target for multiple `BACKUP DATABASE` statements, the resulting file will contain multiple "backup sets" that must be specified in the `RESTORE DATABASE` statement.  Use the `WITH FILE = x` syntax to accomplish that.

Here is a quick test.  First, we create a database:

```
CREATE DATABASE BackupRestoreTest
ON (NAME = 'BackupRestoreTest_system'
    , FILENAME = 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_system.mdf'
    , SIZE = 128MB
    , MAXSIZE = 256MB
    , FILEGROWTH = 128MB)
LOG ON (NAME = 'BackupRestoreTest_log'
    , FILENAME = 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_log.ldf'
    , SIZE = 128MB
    , MAXSIZE = 256MB
    , FILEGROWTH = 128MB);

ALTER DATABASE BackupRestoreTest
SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

Next, we'll take a couple of backups; one for the database itself, and one for the log:

```
BACKUP DATABASE BackupRestoreTest
TO DISK = 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_backup.bak'
WITH INIT
    , NAME = 'Backup Restore Test Database'
    , DESCRIPTION = 'Full Database Backup';

BACKUP LOG BackupRestoreTest
TO DISK = 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_backup.bak'
WITH NOINIT
    , NAME = 'Backup Restore Test Database'
    , DESCRIPTION = 'Log Backup';
```

Notice, the second statement uses with `WITH NOINIT` syntax to ensure we don't obliterate the first backupset stored in the `C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_backup.bak` file.

Now, we look at `RESTORE HEADERONLY` to see what backupsets are in the file:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY 
FROM DISK = 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_backup.bak';
```

A table is displayed, with various information, including a column named "Position", which contains the backupset `FILE=x` number we need for the `RESTORE DATABASE` commands:

[image]

Thus, our `RESTORE` statements look like:

```
RESTORE DATABASE BackupRestoreTest
FROM DISK = 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_backup.bak'
WITH REPLACE
    , NORECOVERY
    , MOVE 'BackupRestoreTest_system' TO 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_system.mdf'
    , MOVE 'BackupRestoreTest_log' TO 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_log.ldf'
    , FILE = 1;

RESTORE DATABASE BackupRestoreTest
FROM DISK = 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_backup.bak'
WITH REPLACE
    , RECOVERY
    , MOVE 'BackupRestoreTest_system' TO 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_system.mdf'
    , MOVE 'BackupRestoreTest_log' TO 'C:\temp\BackupRestoreTest_log.ldf'
    , FILE = 2;
```

Notice, the `FILE = 1` in the first statement, and `FILE = 2` in the second statement.  These denote which backupset we're wanting to restore.

The output from those two restore statements:

> Processed 31 pages for database 'BackupRestoreTest', file 'BackupRestoreTest_system' on file 1.
>   Processed 2 pages for database 'BackupRestoreTest', file 'BackupRestoreTest_log' on file 1.
>   RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 31 pages in 0.322 seconds (7.615 MB/sec).
>
> Processed 0 pages for database 'BackupRestoreTest', file 'BackupRestoreTest_system' on file 2.
>   Processed 3 pages for database 'BackupRestoreTest', file 'BackupRestoreTest_log' on file 2.
>   RESTORE LOG successfully processed 3 pages in 0.059 seconds (0.322 MB/sec).

Notice the second statement shows a `RESTORE LOG`, even though we executed `RESTORE DATABASE`; this is because the backupset stored in file position 2 is a log backup.

I agree with @jyao - it is generally speaking better to use a single backup per file, so you have multiple files since that generally makes things easier to understand and you'll be less likely to "slip up" in an emergency.

Also, unless you are actually using `TO TAPE` syntax, you don't need to specify `NOUNLOAD` and `SKIP`, since they only apply to tape backups.

Comment: This is a well detailed explanation. I wish I could mark this the correct answer. Nice avatar btw.. :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use different backup file names when you do log backup and full backup, so you can do backup like the following

```
-- first do the full backup
BACKUP DATABASE [ICT_IdealComputer]
TO DISK = 'C:\ICT\full_ICTBackup.bak'
WITH NAME = 'ICT-Full Database Backup',
SKIP, init
NOUNLOAD,
STATS = 10

-- 2nd do the log backup
BACKUP LOG [ICT_IdealComputer]
TO DISK = 'C:\ICT\log_ICTBackup.bak'
WITH NAME = 'ICT-Transaction Log Backup',
SKIP, init,
NOUNLOAD,
STATS = 10
```

Then you do restore as follows:

```
USE [master]
GO
-- first restore from full bkup
RESTORE DATABASE ICT_IdealComputer
FROM DISK = 'C:\ICT\full_ICTBackup.bak'
WITH REPLACE, NORECOVERY, 
MOVE 'ICT_IdealComputer' TO   'C:\ICT\ICT_Ideal\App_Data\ICT_IdealComputer.mdf',
MOVE 'ICT_IdealComputer_log' TO 'C:\ICT\ICT_Ideal\App_Data\ICT_IdealComputer_log.ldf';

-- then restore from log backup

RESTORE LOG ICT_IdealComputer
FROM DISK = 'C:\ICT\log_ICTBackup.bak'
WITH RECOVERY;
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why didn't I think of this. I was too stubborn to get it into 1 file I guess.

Comment: @Sas, glad it works for you.